# ScaleMin not working with cf chart in cf 9

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfchart

I am creating a line graph chart in CF 9.
My cfchart code is below:

```
    <cfchart showborder="yes"
    chartheight="500" chartwidth="1000"
    yaxistitle="% Correct" xaxistitle="Month" 
    sortXAxis="yes"
    xAxistype="Scale"
    showxgridlines="yes"
   scaleFrom="1" 
   scaleTo="110" 
   showLegend="yes"
   tipStyle="mouseOver"
   title="Data Entry Audit %">
   </cfchart>
```

Along the X-axis will display the Month Numbers, but it is counting by 2s, instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6 etc.. It is diplaying 0,2,4,6,8. There is data for month of January, so "1", but the 1 does not show up along the x-axis. I tried adding Scalemin=1 and ScaleMax=12, but it seems this is not supported with CF 9. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How many months are you displaying along the x-axis?  Webcharts3D (the underlying charting tool) does a lot of automatic adjustments to ensure the best fit of chart elements. If Webcharts3D is skipping labels, then it may have decided there are too many to *reasonably* fit on along the axis. So it opts to display every other label instead.

I do not think cfchart has an attribute for overriding those particular settings on the *x-axis*. However, you can [use the webcharts3d utility](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-74f2.html) to customize/override the default settings. Specifically, play around with the `xAxis` settings in the "basic" tab (type, scale min/max, etcetera).